# Yii JUI Autocomplete - Pass javascript into sourceUrl

Tags: php, jquery-ui, autocomplete, yii

I am working on a form with 2 autocomplete widgets.  The first widget gets the company name and populates various other items on the form:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'attribute'=>'company_name',
    'model'=>$model,
    'sourceUrl'=>array('company/aclist'),
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'2',
        'select'=>'js: function(e,u){
            $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'company_address').'").val(u.item.address);
            $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'company_phone').'").val(u.item.phone);
            $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'company_id').'").val(u.item.id);
        }',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'size'=>45,
        'maxlength'=>45,
    ),
 ));?>
```

This works perfectly.  The second widget is very similar except it is meant to grab contacts associated with that company.  How do I pass the `company_id` value to the second autocomplete?

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
'sourceUrl'=>array(
    'company/aclist',
    array("id"=>"js:$('#".CHtml::activeId($model,'company_id')."').val();"),
),
```

Anyone have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
'sourceUrl'=>array(
     "company/aclist", "id"=>"js:$('#".CHtml::activeId($model,'company_id')."').val();")
),
```

But I'm afraid there is a problem. I'm almost sure that "js:$(.." would be treat as a string, so it wouldn't be evaluated. So my suggestion is to implement the solution provided [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15828-how-to-paste-params-into-createurl-by-jquery/page__p__78543__hl__createurl+get#entry78543).

That solution is applicable here because 'sourceUrl' invokes CHtml::normalizeUrl(), which in turn calls to CHtml::createUrl(). You would need to change the 'click' event to 'change'. Of course there some other modifications that need to be done, but I hope you can work them out.

Comment: Yeah, still doesn't work.  I saw that solution and was just hoping for a more elegant one.  I already have it working similar to the way that was provided in the link, but just wanted a better way.